# Google Business Api - Pub Sub update notification settings

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub, google-client, google-my-business-api

I'm trying to subscribe to receive notification for every time a new review has been posted for a business using the below code.

```
private static final String topicName = "projects/myproject-12345/topics/business-review";
MyBusiness myBusiness = GMBFactory.getMyBusiness();
    MyBusiness.Accounts.List accountsList = myBusiness.accounts().list();
    ListAccountsResponse response = accountsList.execute();
    List<Account> accounts = response.getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        Notifications notification = new Notifications().setName(topicName);
        UpdateNotifications updateNotification = myBusiness.accounts().updateNotifications(account.getName() + "/notifications",
                notification);
        updateNotification.execute();
    }
```

I get the below error when I try to execute the code.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "reason" : "badRequest"
} ],
"message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

--EDIT--

```
MyBusiness myBusiness = GMBFactory.getMyBusiness();
    MyBusiness.Accounts.List accountsList = myBusiness.accounts().list();
    ListAccountsResponse response = accountsList.execute();
    List<Account> accounts = response.getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        Notifications notification = new Notifications();
        notification.setTopicName(topicName);
        notification.setName("review");
        UpdateNotifications updateNotification = myBusiness.accounts().updateNotifications(account.getName() + "/notifications",
                notification);
        updateNotification.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Notifications`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Notifications) requires the `topicName` and `notificationTypes` to be set. The `name` field is ignored. See https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Notifications

Comment: I've set both the name and topicName, still getting the same error.

Comment: Try also setting `notificationTypes`